# Are blocks that are read from LVM kept in Linux's block cache?

Tags: linux, lvm, memory-usage, block-device

Does Linux keep blocks that are read from an LVM logical volume in the block cache as it does with blocks read from a "regular" block device or is the IO direct?

Also, do the usual buffering semantics apply for writing to a logical volume?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LV -> dm or md device -> sdX -> block layer

This is how an IO goes in case of LVM. If you run blktrace or systemtap, it should be clearer.